# How to make test in this situation?

Tags: php

There are two `array`s :

```
$tClasseMenu = array();
$tDroitsClassMenu = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $data['user']['classMenus']['cnt']; $i++)
{
    $tClasseMenu[$i] = $data['user']['classMenus'][$i]['class_menu_code'];
    for ($j = 0; $j < $data['user']['droit']['cnt']; $j++)
    {
        $tDroitsClassMenu[$i][$j] = $data['user']['droit'][$j]['class_menu_code'];
    }
}
```

An example of data from these arrays are :

```
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 7 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 8 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 3 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 1 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 5 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 6 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 4 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = 2 , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 6
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 4
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 2
class_menu_code = , droit classmenucode = 2
```

How to test if a value in $tClasseMenu is present in $tDroitsClassMenu ?

Answer (score 1):

PHP's native [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function will tell you which values in one array, appear in another:

```
$result = array_intersect( $tClassMenu, $tDroitsClassMenu );
```

If `$result` is empty, you had no intersecting points. Otherwise, `$result` will be populated with all points that intersected between the two arrays.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: It returns null ! I think it's because of the two dimensionnal array tDroitsClassMenu !

Comment: I use array_search instead, Thanks !